# Xcode 9.2 build warnings with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm new to Firebase. I'm trying to add Firebase to my project.
This is my pod file:

```html
platform :ios, '11.2'
target 'CapstoneDesign' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

Xcode complains with 25 warnings when I built the project. What should I do?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phUEu.png)

Comment: What about... nothing? This is just a bunch of warnings about 3 part library.

Comment: Hmm. Something else may be going on. I just built a brand new iOS project, Swift 4, Firebase 4, Xcode 9.2. I used the Cocoapods app to add the Firebase dependencies; quit XCode, started Cocoapods, Then File->New File from Xcode project and I copy and pasted your pod file. Installed it, quit Cocopods and the launched the newly created Workspace. It built and ran with no errors. Maybe your process is different? Are you launching the workspace (.xcworkspace ) that was created in instead of the project file (.xcodeproj)?

Comment: @Jay As detailed in an answer comment below, the warnings show up with version 1.5.6 of the CocoaPods/Xcodeproj gem

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do about closed-source 3rd party libaries like Firebase. You can, however, suppress these warnings using the `inhibit_all_warnings!` directive in your Podfile.

Comment: That's correct but then your app crashes and doesn't work properly because it's trying to read a variable from somewhere else in the code instead of the variable you want it to read. This particular warning is very important as if you reference a variable called user (which was a globally defined User or even a Firebase User *Class*) instead of self.user (local to the class) then your results will be unknown and intermittent - the compiler won't know which *user* you really want to access.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing warnings from pods installed by Firebase, please file an issue to the [Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues) or other appropriate GitHub project.

For example, last week's [CocoaPods/XcodeProj release](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/releases/tag/1.5.6) turned on [additional default Xcode warnings](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/commit/f356891db634b68710b5c78611b84c14371acd7a) that led to some Firebase dependencies building with warnings.

I created this [GTMSessionFetcher issue](https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher/issues/110) and [this gRPC issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14390).

Comment: It looks like that issue was closed / merged. It's not clear ( to me) why however. Was this an use you personally duplicated or was it based on the issue the OP here was reporting. Just curious as we are not seeing that issue even after creating multiple projects similar to the OP's. Does that mean it was resolved or is something that's upcoming or being worked on.Thanks!

Comment: Yes the GTMSessionFetcher warnings will show up if you run pod install/update and have the Xcodeproj gem version 1.5.6 installed.  You can also reproduce the "Block implicitly retains self ..." warnings by setting the Xcode setting CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF on the build of the GTMSessionFetcher pod to Yes.   The GTMSessionFetcher fix has not yet been pushed - https://cocoapods.org/pods/GTMSessionFetcher is still showing latest release of January 2018.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Interestingly, I do a $gem list and do not seem to have the XCodeProj gem installed at all. We build a variety of different projects on a daily basis and have been working with Firebase for over 3 years. I wonder why we are missing that component - it would explain why we are not getting that particular error. Is there anything that can be uninstalled to prevent the OP's error in the first place?

Comment: Try `gem list xcodeproj`. You could go back to an old version to prevent OP's error, but 1.5.6 will soon be CocoaPods default - so getting the Pods fixed is important.

Comment: Tried that - nothing installed. Output is only *** LOCAL GEMS ***.. and nothing following. I actually do development on 4 different Macs and none of them have Xcodeproj gem version 1.5.6 installed. Guess my workflow doesn't include installing that. Thanks for the great info though!

Comment: If you're using cocoapods, you must have xcodeproj installed somewhere. `xcodeproj` is a dependency of cocoapods. If you do `gem dependency cocoapods`, xcodeproj will be in the output.

Comment: huh. Well, I literally just created a new Project and added Firebase to it via the CocoaPods App. That being said, at least on this MacBook Pro, I have not installed the command line tools. When I run *gem dependency cocoapods* from the commend line, I get *No gems found matching cocoapods (>= 0)*. Obviously this is going way off topic but I must be doing something different for the last X years using Cocoapods.

Comment: Looks like everything is bundled into the CocoaPods App - so since you aren't installing the component gems separately to the command line, you won't see this issue exposed by the latest Xcodeproj until the next version of the App.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last week after deleting BOLTS pod from my Podfile, i thought maybe this might be a cause but it wasn't, however I went to my Firebase Database rules and set them to default, now it's working ;)